# Phonegap web-service with Basic Auth

Tags: web-services, cordova, basic-authentication

In my PhoneGap application I need to call a service that uses Basic Auth. 
The service works (see postman, the credentials are test:test):
[image]

I'm testing the service in Chrome and Android device then I'm getting:

[image]

My jQuery code:

```
function getData(){
    var newDataRequest = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'myurl',
        dataType: 'json',
        /*username: 'test',
        password: 'test',*/
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader ('Authorization', 'Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0'); },
        timeout: 30000 // timeout after 30 seconds
        /*data: { user: "test", psw: "test" }*/
    });

    newDataRequest.done(function(msg)
    {
        alert("success");
    });

    newDataRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus)
    {
        alert("ERROR #" + jqXHR.status + "  " + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}
```

How do make it works on Android, IOS and browser(for testing) ?